# JavaScript Error: conditional compilation is turned off in MVC2 View

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to call a JavaScript function on click in a MVC2 View Page.

```
 <a onclick=" SelectBenefit(<%=o.ba_Object_id %>,<%=o.ba_Object_Code %>)" href="#">Select</a>
```

JavaScript function

```
 function SelectBenefit(id,code) {
     alert(id);
     alert(code);
 }
```

Here ba_Object_Id and Code are the values from the ViewModel. If I use `SelectBenefit(<%=o.ba_Object_id %>)` in this way, its working fine. But when I have two paramaters its not.I am getting this error:

```
conditional compilation is turned off.
```

Comment: Can you show us the rendered HTML? I.e. what do you see when you view source?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that you need to put quotes around the second parameter if it is a string:

```
<a onclick=" SelectBenefit(<%=o.ba_Object_id %>, '<%=o.ba_Object_Code %>')" href="#">Select</a>
```

This being said your parameters need to be properly encoded and I wouldn't pass them likse this. I would serialize them as JSON object to ensure that everything is OK. Like this:

```
<a onclick="SelectBenefit(<%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { id = o.ba_Object_id, code = o.ba_Object_Code }) %>)" href="#">Select</a>
```

and then the SelectBenefit function might look like this:

```
function SelectBenefit(benefit) {
    alert(benefit.id);
    alert(benefit.code);
}
```

Comment: @patel.milanb, it's the second code snippet (using a `JavaScriptSerializer`) that I would actually recommend, so don't make the mistake of using what I showed on the first code snippet.

Comment: Hi Darin, can you please have a look at my this question..i would appreciate your views on that ...thx 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409195/error-while-accessing-the-navigation-property-in-ef-code-first

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing `o.ba_Object_Code` is not a number? Try putting quotes around it:

```
<a onclick="SelectBenefit(<%=o.ba_Object_id %>,'<%=o.ba_Object_Code %>')" href="#">Select</a>
```

You could also write this function like this:

```
<a href="javascript:SelectBenefit(<%=o.ba_Object_id %>,'<%=o.ba_Object_Code %>');">Select</a>
```

Or use Jquery (best approach, imo):

```
$('#yourlinkid').click(function(){
     SelectBenefit(<%=o.ba_Object_id %>,'<%=o.ba_Object_Code %>');
     return false;
});
```