# Error while accessing the Navigation Property in EF Code First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, view

I am having a simple ViewModel which have something like this...

## ViewModel

```
public class UserPostCommentViewModel
    {

        public virtual List<Comment> Comment { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    }
```

so that i can return a view which has 1 Post with the details 1 User details and Many Comments submitted by users....

## POST

```
 [Key]
        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        public int PostID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Required")]
        [StringLength(250)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Required")]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Body { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int? TagID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

        public virtual User Users { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
```

## Comment

```
[Key]
        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        public int CommentID { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Your Comment")]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Body { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        public int PostID { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        public User User { get; set; }

        public Post Posts { get; set; }
```

## USer

```
[ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        [Key]
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(15)]
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage="First Name is Required")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(15)]
        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is Required")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress,ErrorMessage="please enter valid email")]
        [DisplayName("Email Address")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is Required")]
        [Remote("CheckUniqueEmail","User",ErrorMessage="An account with this email address already exists.")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is Required")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        public DateTime JoiningDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        public DateTime? LastActivityDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
```

i have a StronglyTyped View with the ViewModel so that i can return all the three model properties in one view...

BUT :( i want to show the userName instead of userID in front of the each comment for that particular post. so i am using ICollection comments in the viewmodel so that i can return collection of the comments. and when i try to access the  userName property like this @Model.Comments.User.LastName // OR Email // OR FirstName .. i am getting the compilation error. and i cant use like this because its a collection type ...

how can i retrieve the userName from the comments entity using the userID which is available in comments..

please help...

Got it all working by adding in the partial view..

## _Comments Partial View..

in my partial view i have added like this...

========================

```
@{
    ContextRepository db = new ContextRepository();
    var userID = Model.UserID;
    var userName = db.EUser.Find(userID).FirstName;   

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a partial view to display the comment and call that inside a loop in the main view.

**Post Details view**

```
@model UserPostCommentViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Post";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@foreach (Comment comment in Model.Comments)
{
    @Html.Partial("_Comment", comment);
}
```

**_Comment partial view**

```
@model Comment

<div class="comment">
    <div class="desc">@Model.Body</div>

    <div class="submitted-by">@Model.User.LastName</div>
</div>
```

Model issues

You need to make the navigational properties virtual to be lazy loaded.

```
public class Comment
{
    //other properties

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public virtual Post Posts { get; set; }
}
```

If you are going to access these navigational properties then you need to eager load them. Otherwise you will run into `Select n+1` problem. Use the `Include` method to eager load properties

```
var post = db.Posts.Include(p => Comments)
            .Include(p => p.Comments.Select(c => c.User))
            .Where(p => p.PostID == 1).Single();
```

Comment: Hey ..thanks... i tried this and got the following error...

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

<p><div class="submitted-by">@Model.User.FirstName</div></p>

its a null reference exception ...

Comment: well...i used something like this and now its working... learned the new approach though from your answer.. thx for sharing +1