# Call function created in view using javascript in the same view

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have created a view which contains both Javascript and functions as shown:

```
@functions
{
    public int DaysInMonth(string Month)
    {
         //code to get the no of days in month;
    }
}
```

I have drop down list that contains month..
Now I want to write code on dropdownlist's change event using jQuery which will call the above function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#Months').live('change', function () { 
           //code to call the above function  
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here `('#Months') is the id` of the dropdownlist..

Note: Both the above code snippets are in the same view (Index).

How can i link the above two code snippets??

Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@functions
{
    public int DaysInMonth(string Month)
    {
         //code to get the no of days in month;
    }
}
```

try like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @DaysInMonth(month);
</script>
```

it worked fine in my program.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/*@cc_on @*/

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#Months').live('change', function () { 
           var monthSelected = $(this).val();
           //code to call the above function 
           @DaysInMonth(monthSelected);
        });
    });
</script>
```

More info on this is at:
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/173/The-Difference-Between-@Helpers-and-@Functions-In-WebMatrix

Also have a look at this answer:
[JavaScript Error: conditional compilation is turned off in MVC2 View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686283/javascript-error-conditional-compilation-is-turned-off-in-mvc2-view)

Comment: how to turn on the conditional compilation?

Comment: /*@cc_on @*/ this will turn it on